# Are we really sure that the whole universe is expanding?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion

Haven't we thought about the possibility of only a region of the universe is expanding?

What about space is expanding in this region and space is compressed in another region, that    satisfies the conservation law of space, no space can be created or destroyed.

So we can't be sure that the whole universe is expanding but we know that space as far as we can measure is expanding. Am I right about that?

Comment: What conservation law of space?

Comment: @RobJeffries Total amount of space remains constant.

Comment: I'm unaware of such a conservation law.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a commonly considered idea, of which one variant is the "[Hubble bubble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_Bubble_%28astronomy%29)".  Anything that happens outside of the visible universe, is, after all, in principle unknowable to us.